# Retrieve specific record using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to retrieve a specific record from Data Base using Hibernate. What I want to do is commented below in the function.

```
public List<Customer> showCustomer(long customerIdFromCustomerListPage)
        throws Exception {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        **//Select * from Customers where customerId="customerIdFromCustomerListPage"**

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return customerList;

}
```

Comment: How about reading some Hibernate documentation? This is extremely basic stuff. BTW, it doesn't make much sense to return a list if you're interested in a single customer. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29 and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-loading

Comment: Yes you are right, I just gave an example demo example of what I wanna do,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
 public Customer getCustomer(Long customerIdFromCustomerListPage)
    throws Exception {

      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Customer customer = (Customer )session.get(Customer.class, customerIdFromCustomerListPage); 
      return customer ;

}
```

Comment: How to iterate the object (Customer) got from above code in Jsp using JSTL? It is giving an Error saying " Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt; "..

Comment: it is object you can't iterate it you just have to use it without iterating